# Selecting from multiple tables with semi-join

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query. It produces an error that `Unknown column 'lp.amount' in 'field list'`

```
SELECT l.*, SUM(lp.amount) AS landPayMonth, p.pName, u.uName, SUM(ci.amount) AS totAmnt, t.unitId FROM (SELECT distinct landlord_payment.id FROM landlord_payment) lp, (SELECT distinct cashIn.id FROM cashIn) ci, landlords l, properties p, units u, tenants t WHERE ci.tenantId=t.id AND l.id=lp.landlordId AND t.unitId=u.id AND u.propertyId=p.id AND p.landlordId=l.id AND STR_TO_DATE(ci.registeredTime, "%Y-%m")=STR_TO_DATE(CURDATE(), "%Y-%m")
GROUP BY l.id;
```

Please help me out.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're trying to do. Put some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    l.*,SUM(lp.amount) AS landPayMonth,p.pName,u.uName,SUM(ci.amount) AS totAmnt,
    t.unitId
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT landlord_payment.id,landlord_payment.amount,landlord_payment.landlordId FROM landlord_payment) lp,
    (SELECT DISTINCT cashIn.id,cashIn.tenantId,cashIn.registeredTime,cashIn.amount FROM cashIn) ci,landlords l,properties p,units u,tenants t
WHERE
    ci.tenantId = t.id
        AND l.id = lp.landlordId
        AND t.unitId = u.id
        AND u.propertyId = p.id
        AND p.landlordId = l.id
        AND STR_TO_DATE(ci.registeredTime, '%Y-%m') = STR_TO_DATE(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m')
GROUP BY l.id;
```

You can try above code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Did when your query wasn't working. Seems to be accepted now :)